# Test of good fitting on a sigmoid

Tags: chi-squared-test, fitting, curve-fitting, sigmoid-curve

as you can see on the figure i linked i am currently fitting my data (which looks like a sigmoid) using a function i defined with 5 parameters.

```
def sigmoid(x, L, x0, k, b, e):
y = (L + e*x) / (1 + np.exp(-k*(x-x0))) + b 
return y
```

then as i said i'd like to have an idea of how good my fit is (kolmogorov, chi2) so i went to determine what's the critical chi square value: here my degrees of freedom are the number of points i consider for my fit minus the numbers of parameters = 25000 - 5 that gives a chisquare crit = 25384. The value I have with my fit is 0.6... which is way smaller than the critical one but is it normal to have that much of a difference ? Which criterion could I put in order to know wether the fit is great or not.

Thanks for any help.

[image]

Comment: (1) Why does the graph of the fit appear only in the middle? (2) There's no way the chi-squared statistic for these data is $0.6.$  How exactly did you compute that number?

Comment: @whuber  Well i chose to only fit this specific region (less points to fit / faster to compute), i then used the scipy library like so: (counts lists= raw data)
`import scipy.stats as stats`
`df = len(x[x_med-pm_xmed:x_med+pm_xmed]) - len(p0)`
`chi_square_test_statistic, p_value = stats.chisquare((Counts_list[i])[x_med-pm_xmed:x_med+pm_xmed], data_fit_sig)`
  
ps: i have the same when doing like this:
`observed = Counts_list[i][x_med-pm_xmed:x_med+pm_xmed]
expected = data_fit_sig
chi_square = np.sum(np.abs((observed - expected)**2 / expected))`

Comment: the problem probably comes from the fact that my degrees of freedom are equal to the number of points i plot and hence way to high resulting in a very high critical chi square value ?

Comment: I suspect whatever values might be in `observed` or `expected` are incorrect, because it's mathematically impossible to obtain a chi-squared value of 0.6 with data like those you have shown.  I would believe a number closer to 0.6 multiplied by 25000.

Comment: Yes that is what i thought but after looking up at some examples on how to use this library no one faced this kind of problem so no one had to multiply by the number of points they are considering

Comment: If you would like our help with this, then please consider creating a minimal reproducible example and showing the details.  You should be able to create an example using just a handful of judiciously chosen data points.